# Plotting a line graph from a starting point other than the origin - s3.js

Tags: c3.js

I'm trying to plot data on a line graph where the x-axis are the months January to December.

The issue is: I can't seem to commence the line graph from anything other than the x-axis origin - which would be January.

Question - How can I set a start point, so the data line is plotted from **March** to **December**.  I could set the data to be 0 for Jan and Feb, but I don't want the line to appear at these months.

Via http://c3js.org/samples/simple_regions.html - I can see you can set start and end regions to specify different types of lines (in this case dashes).  Is there a similar way to set a start and end so January and February are hidden.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a `null` data point.

Here's sample code:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data', null, null, 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250]
        ]
    }
});
```

Here's the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jrdsxvys/1/

Comment: You're a gent! Thank you very much